# Exact association record with has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have following code in my models:

```
class Investment < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :investment_datas
  has_many :investors, through: :investment_datas, source: :investor

class Investor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :investment_datas
  has_many :investments, through: :investment_datas, source: :investment

class InvestmentData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :investor
  belongs_to :investment
```

I have some fields in `InvestmentData` that I want to access for specific `Investor` and `Investment`. For example, like this:

```
investor.investments.first.investment_data
```

It gives an error:

```
NoMethodError undefined method 'investment_data' for #<Investment:0x000000070f3028>
```

Where `investment_data` is the `InvestmentData` record which connects `investor` and `investments.first` records.

How can I achieve this with `ActiveRecord`? Or should I go with raw SQL?

Comment: Please expand on "it doesn't work though". What exactly *is* happening? Is it returning the wrong data? Is it returning nothing? Is it throwing an error?

Comment: Exactly. No method error

Comment: Please include the exact error in your question.

Comment: The reason it's throwing that error is because you don't have an `investment_data` relationship on your `Investment` model. You have an `investment_datas` (plural) relationship.

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> Where investment_data is the InvestmentData record which connects investor and investments.first records.

Then you can do:

```
InvestmentData.where(investor_id: investor.id, investment_id: investments.first.id).first
# or
investor.investment_datas.where(investment_id: investments.first.id).first
# or
investments.first.investment_datas.where(investor_id: investor.id).first
```

Comment: This solution produces N + 1 problem, cause I have to display data in `.each` loop

Comment: nothing blocks you from eager loading the relations before the loop @starwars25

Comment: If I do that, will results of first queries be cached and used in following queries?

Comment: Try it to find this out